# Export data from livelink

Tags: java, migration, export, utility, livelink

I have to export data from livelink and import into other content management application. I am new to the LiveLink and its functionality.

Can some one suggest me the best ways to export data from livelink?

Please share the links/documents/code related to this.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you have two options, if you have to export data from LL:

1. Create an own C# / JAVA application that can export data from LiveLink. For this purpose you (or your developer) have to use LiveLink API (supported for LL 9.5 - 9.7.1 / CS 10.5) or LiveLink web services.
2. Use third party tools: Tzunami, Xillio, Ecmwise, Avepoint or DMS-Shuttle.
   You can test the DMS-Shuttle 15 days trial in your environment and decide if it fits your needs. http://dms-shuttle.com/features/dms-shuttle-livelink/. I'm working for the vendor.